# Fatal error: Call to a member function getSubMenu() on a non-object in /.../admin/index.php on line 24

Tags: php

I have following code to call a menu and submenu from my db.

Calling the parent menu is nu problem but when I want to call my child menu I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSubMenu() on a non-object in /.../admin/index.php on line 24

On `index.php` I first call my parent menu by:

```
<?php $arrMenu = $menu->getMenu(); ?>
```

Then I call my child menu by:

```
<?php $arrSubMenu = $menu->getSubMenu(); ?>
```

This code gives the above error code.

This is my code for my menu class

```
<?php
class Menu {
    private $log;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(Log $log, Connection $conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function getMenu() {
        $prefix = $this->conn->getPrefix();

        $sqlMenu = "SELECT name FROM ".$prefix."modules WHERE active = '1' AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY rank ASC";
        $arrMenu = $this->conn->select($sqlMenu);

        return $arrMenu;
    }

    public function getSubMenu(){

    }
}

$menu = new Menu($log, $conn);

?>
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: The function getSubMenu() in your class is empty?

Comment: Something is probably trashing `$menu`, turning it into a "non-object", exactly as your error message is saying. do a `var_dump($menu)` to see what's in there when you try calling getSubMenu(), and then go backwards and figure out where $menu is being overwritten.

Comment: Can you show us the first 25 lines of admin/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a real instance of that object, you cannot just have

`$menu = new Menu($log, $conn);` your Menu class. because `$log` and `$conn` are not defined parameters.

This is how you should use it

```
<?php
include 'Menu.php';

$log = Log();
$conn = new Connection();
$menu = new Menu($log, $conn);
```

then you will be able to use the object:

```
<?php $arrMenu = $menu->getMenu(); ?>
```